How to copy ALL install-time Play Asset Deliver files to my app's file system on Android?
My Android app is using install-time Play Asset Delivery to deliver all my game's assets. This asset folder is an arbitrary hierarchy of directories that I need to copy verbatim into my app's file system.
How can I copy this directory structure when AssetManager only provides an InputStream?
I'd like to use something simple like this but it doesn't work.
val assetRoot = assetManager.open("/")
val gameDataRoot = FileOuputStream("/gamedata/")
assetRoot.copyTo(gameDataRoot)

Is there some other approach that would work?

While I didn't find a direct way to do this in the Android SDK, I did find a work-around using the technique outlined in this post. Accessing play asset package directly
You can treat the assets package as a .zip file and decompress your assets directly into your Android file system using Zip4j or other methods.
